# Optaplanner - Drools accumulate function reverseSupport Exception

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

Hi i'm using optaplanner with drools and i have a rule using accumulate max inside it. There isn't any problem during solving but after solve i wanna learn which rules create constraint and i'm using this code below.

```
 List<ConstraintMatchTotal> constraintMatchTotalList = null;
            do {
                try {
                    constraintMatchTotalList
                            = solutionBusiness.getConstraintMatchTotalList();
                    check = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (counter < 9) {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        counter++;
                    } else {
                        logClass.addExceptionLog(e, scenario.getIdx());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } while (!check && counter < 10);
```

First 5 round this method throws exception but after that it works except to include accumulate function's rule [checkMaxDeadlineWithoutJava]

There is my rule

```
rule "checkMaxDeadlineWithoutJava"
salience 21
when
      Action(this != null, $taskId: getTaskId(), getMaxDeadline() > 0)
      accumulate( Action(this != null, $endTime : getEndTime(), getTaskId() == $taskId),
                        $max : max( $endTime ))
      $action : Action(this != null, getEndTime() == $max, $taskId == getTaskId(), $maxDeadLine: getMaxDeadline())
eval((int) $maxDeadLine < (int) $max)
then
System.out.println("maxDead" + $maxDeadLine);
System.out.println("max" + $max);
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -21);
end
```

And this is the Exception which one is throwed first 5 round of retry;

> 10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2) Exception executing consequence
>   for rule "checkMaxDeadlineWithoutJava" in
>   org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.Core.solver:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Accumulate function (max)
>   used in rule(s) [checkMaxDeadlineWithoutJava] does not have
>   reverseSupport 10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)  at
>   org.drools.core.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.java:39)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.handleException(DefaultAgenda.java:1247)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.innerFireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:438)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.fireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:379)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.fire(RuleExecutor.java:135)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:88)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:34)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:1067)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1014)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1006)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1318)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1309)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1293)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.drools.DroolsScoreDirector.getConstraintMatchTotals(DroolsScoreDirector.java:134)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.optaplanner.examples.common.business.SolutionBusiness.getConstraintMatchTotalList(SolutionBusiness.java:259)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.Core.business.CalculatorClass.endSolver(CalculatorClass.java:325)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.Core.business.CalculatorClass$2.run(CalculatorClass.java:226)
>   10:58:20,145 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) 10:58:20,145 ERROR
>   [stderr] (Timer-2)    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
>   10:58:20,146 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2) Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Accumulate function (max)
>   used in rule(s) [checkMaxDeadlineWithoutJava] does not have
>   reverseSupport 10:58:20,146 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)  at
>   org.drools.core.reteoo.FromNodeLeftTuple.getAccumulatedObjects(FromNodeLeftTuple.java:105)
>   10:58:20,146 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.common.AgendaItem.getObjectsDeep(AgendaItem.java:79)
>   10:58:20,146 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.reteoo.RuleTerminalNodeLeftTuple.getObjectsDeep(RuleTerminalNodeLeftTuple.java:359)
>   10:58:20,146 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.api.score.holder.AbstractScoreHolder.extractJustificationList(AbstractScoreHolder.java:118)
>   10:58:20,146 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.api.score.holder.AbstractScoreHolder.registerConstraintMatch(AbstractScoreHolder.java:88)
>   10:58:20,146 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardmediumsoft.HardMediumSoftScoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(HardMediumSoftScoreHolder.java:58)
>   10:58:20,146 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.Core.solver.Rule_checkMaxDeadlineWithoutJava699319029.defaultConsequence(Rule_checkMaxDeadlineWithoutJava699319029.java:23)
>   10:58:20,146 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.Core.solver.Rule_checkMaxDeadlineWithoutJava699319029DefaultConsequenceInvokerGenerated.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source) 10:58:20,146 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.Core.solver.Rule_checkMaxDeadlineWithoutJava699319029DefaultConsequenceInvoker.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source) 10:58:20,146 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     at
>   org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.innerFireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:431)
>   10:58:20,146 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-2)     ... 17 more

Comment: What version of OptaPlanner/Drools is this? I remember a fix for something (similar?) in a recent version. Try 7.11.

Comment: optaplanner 7.3.2 --- drools 7.6.0. i will try thanks

Comment: The optaplanner and drools version should be the same.